# Find how many solutions there are for modular congruence equation.

Tags: matrices

I need to find how many solutions there are, when $A=A^{-1}$ and $A$ is $2 \times 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$. I know that $\det(A) \equiv \pm 1 \pmod {26}$. Hence I have
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{bmatrix} = \det(A)^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c & a\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$\det(A)=ad-bc$$
I use Chinese Reminder Theory to find how many solutions there are in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$. Then I can find how many solutions there are overall in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$.
But I run into a problem when I consider this in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$, when $\det(A)\equiv-1\pmod{13}$. From matrix equivalence I have that
$$\begin{cases}
  a=-d\\
  b=b \\
  c=c \\
  d=-a\\
  ad-bc \equiv -1 \pmod{13}
\end{cases}$$.
How can I find how many solutions there are for equation $ad-bc \equiv -1 \pmod{13}$ or $-a^2-bc \equiv -1 \pmod{13}$?

Comment: Solutions... **to what** ??

Comment: Sorry for being amiguous. I need to find how many matrices there are that holds $A=A^{-1}$. Just a count no need for particular matrices.

Comment: but then why $\;\det A=\pm 1\;$ ? The determinant must be a unit modulo $\;26\;$ for the matrix to be invertible...or is it *another* condition?

Comment: It is given that determinant can be 1 or -1 in modulo 26 and it follows the same for modulo 13. I just need a way to find how many unique solutions there are for $-a^2-bc \equiv -1 (mod13)$.

Comment: I don't get it: the determinant.."*can*" be $\;\pm1\;$ ir else it is **given** that $\;A=A^{-1}\;$ **and** $\;\det A=\pm1\;$ ?

Comment: I had to prove it that determinant is always 1 or -1 when $A=A^{-1}$, because $A*A^{-1}=I_n$ and $det {I_n}= \pm 1$, hence $det(A)= \pm 1 (mod26)$. And Im allowed to use it for finding a number of possible unique matrices that holds equality $A=A^{-1}$. I consider it in modulo 2 and modulo 13 (CRT) to find how many solutions there are in modulo 26. Also I consider these two cases with both $det(A)=1$ and $det(A)=-1$. And thats when I run into problem, because I get $-a^2-bc \equiv -1 (mod13)$ and don't know how to find the count of possible $a,b,c,d$ sets that would hold for $A=A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

We seek the cardinality of the matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\mathbb{Z}_{13})$ s.t. $a^2+bc=1$.

Case 1: $c\not=0$, then $b=\dfrac{1-a^2}{c}$, that is $13.12=156$ solutions.

Case 2: if $c=0$, then $a=\pm 1$, that is $13.2=26$ solutions.

The required cardinality is $156+26=182$ non-trivial solutions.

We must add the $2$ obvious solutions $\pm I_2$ and there are $184$ matrices $A\in M_2(\mathbb{Z}_{13})$ s.t. $A^2=I_2$.